# How to pass dynamic arrays in FreePascal correctly

Tags: parameter-passing, freepascal, dynamic-arrays

In this FreePascal code I write, I found that in a dynamic array of length 'n', it always contained a random value in element 'n'.

I understand why that is, however, I am wondering if perhaps there is a flaw in the way i've written my code. I've pasted it below. I'd welcome any corrections.

```
program LinearSearch;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

uses
  {$IFDEF UNIX}{$IFDEF UseCThreads}
  cthreads,
  {$ENDIF}{$ENDIF}
  Classes, SysUtils
  { you can add units after this };

{$R *.res}

type
  ArrayOfByte = array of Byte;

Function findMaximum(studentMarks : ArrayOfByte; numberOfStudents : integer)
: integer;
var
  maximumMark : Integer;
  studentWithMaximumMark : Integer;
  index : integer;
begin
  setLength(studentMarks, numberOfStudents);
  maximumMark := studentMarks[0];

  for index:=0 to numberOfStudents do
  begin
    write(IntToStr(studentMarks[index]));
    if index = numberOfStudents then writeln('.')
    else write(',');
  end;

  for index:= 0 to (numberOfStudents - 1) do
  begin
      if studentMarks[index] > maximumMark then
      begin
           maximumMark := studentMarks[index];
           studentWithMaximumMark := index;
        end;
  end;
  write('Maximum score of ',IntToStr(maximumMark),' was achieved by ');
  Result := studentWithMaximumMark+1;
end;

var
  studentMarks : ArrayOfByte;
  numberOfStudents : Integer;
  studentWithMaximumMarks : Integer;
  counter : integer;
begin
  write('Enter the number of students: ' );
  readln(numberOfStudents);
  setLength(studentMarks,numberOfStudents);

  writeln('Input the grades for the following students:');
  for counter := 0 to (numberOfStudents - 1) do
  begin
    write('Student ',counter+1,': ');
    readln(studentMarks[counter]);
  end;
  writeln('Data has been input. Finding student with maximum marks.');

  studentWithMaximumMarks := findMaximum(studentMarks,numberOfStudents);
  write('student no. ',IntToStr(studentWithMaximumMarks));
  writeln;
  writeln('Press ANY key to continue');
  readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 5):

In Free Pascal dynamic arrays are **zero based**. So the first element is `MyArray[0]` and last element is `MyArray[High(MyArray)]` which is equal to `MyArray[Length(MyArray) - 1]`. You should never access `MyArray[Length(MyArray)]`.

Answer (score 1):

`...I found that in a dynamic array of length 'n', it always contained a random value in element 'n'.` this is because you are accessing a value beyond of the bounds of the array, check in the procedure `findMaximum` the line

```
for index:=0 to numberOfStudents do
```

must be

```
for index:=0 to numberOfStudents-1 do
```

Also you can remove the first line of the same procedure `setLength(studentMarks, numberOfStudents);`

Comment: Exactly, dynamic arrays "know" their length.